# Moving an object towards a point in javascript

Tags: javascript, math

Im struggling with the maths for this, I need to move an object evenly towards a point. I have a point at x:500 y:250 and an object at 0,0. With a movement speed of '1' how would I work out that to get the that point I would need to move at a rate of x:0.666 and y:0.333. The y speed being half of the x speed. Im sure i am just being an absolute idiot here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, determine the angle of approach using atan2.

```
dx = 500 - 0;
dy = 250 - 0;
angle = atan2(dy, dx)
```

Using the angle, you can decompose your velocity into its x and y components.

```
xVelocity = velocity * cos(angle);
yVelocity = velocity * sin(angle);
```

For your example problem, this will give xVelocity equal to 0.8944 and yVelocity equal to 0.4472, which looks about right. (Your initial guess of 0.666 and 0.333 isn't accurate, since then your total movement speed would be 0.745.)

Comment: Works perfectly thank you, the comment on the total movement speed being 0.745, I understand that I was incorrect but could you explain why that is the case since they both add up to 9.9r or '1'?

Comment: Jack explained it in his post. Total velocity isn't calculated by addition, but by the Pythagorean formula. sqrt(0.8944^2 + 0.4472^2) == 1.

Answer (score 7):

First you compute the delta between the source point and the destination point:

```
var dx = destX - srcX;
var dy = destY - srcY;
```

Then you compute the angle between the two points with the `atan2` function:

```
var angle = Math.atan(dy, dx);
```

Now that you have the angle you can compute the velocity vector through magnitude (1) and the angle:

```
var magnitude = 1.0;
var velX = Math.cos(angle) * magnitude;
var velY = Math.sin(angle) * magnitude;
```

Don't mix up magnitude with the sum of components of a vector, the formula `v.x + v.y = 1.0` is not correct, because the magnitude is the square root of the sum of squared components so the correct formula would be `Math.sqrt(v.x*v.x + v.y*y.y) = 1`

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, I have been confusing the two!

Comment: typo: `atan` in 2nd code snippet should be `atan2`

Comment: How would one add a "speed" parameter?

Comment: I converted it to a TypeScript function: `type Vector2 = [number, number];

function moveTowardsEntity(
  currentPosition: Vector2,
  targetPosition: Vector2,
  speed: number,
): Vector2 {
  let dx = targetPosition[0] - currentPosition[0];
  let dy = targetPosition[1] - currentPosition[1];
  let angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
  return [speed * Math.cos(angle), speed * Math.sin(angle)];
}`

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this:

```
function calculateSpeed(x1, y1, x2, y2)
{
    x = x2 - x1;
    y = y2 - y1;
    total = x + y;

    speedX = x / total;
    speedY = y / total;

    alert("x: " + speedX + " y: " + speedY);
}
```

So you need to calculate the difference between the point x1 and x2, same with y, then calculate the total of thos difference and divide x/y by it !

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LpVd3/) for an example

Comment: The total value is wrong there, it should be sqrt(x^2 + y^2) = the distance travelled during 1 unit of time.