# How do I make something move toward the cursor or a component at a certain speed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a little game using HTML, JavaScript, and CSS. It is modeled off of possibly the most famous game of 2012 - Slender: The Eight Pages. I want to make my Slenderman component to move toward the mouse cursor or a component.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <style>
     canvas {
     border:2px solid grey;
     background-color: forestgreen;
     }
    </style>
   </head>
 <body onload="startForest()">

<script>
  var Slendyman;

  function startForest() {
    Slendyman = new component(15, 15, "black", 675, 1330);
    Forest.start();
  }

  var Forest = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
      this.canvas.width = 1350;
      this.canvas.height = 1350;
      this.canvas.style.cursor = "none"; //hide the original cursor
      this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
      document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
      this.interval = setInterval(updateForest, 20);
      window.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
        Forest.x = e.pageX;
        Forest.y = e.pageY;
      })
    }, 
    clear : function(){
      this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
  }
  function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;    
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;    
    this.update = function() {
      ctx = Forest.context;
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
  }

  function updateForest() {
    Forest.clear();
    if (Forest.x && Forest.y) {
      Slendyman.x = Forest.x;
      Slendyman.y = Forest.y;        
    }
    Slendyman.update();
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want Slendyman to move toward the player or mouse. But I want it to take time, because instantly going to it is not what I want. I want it to move at a constant speed that I can change with a variable. In this case, I want a variable, "Pages", to change the speed. As in, the higher the number Pages is, the faster Slendyman moves. (like in the real game.)
The parts that are different is the fact that it is moving at a constant speed toward the cursor or a component, which can move around, and the speed can be changed by a variable.

What happens with my code is that it just goes to the spot the cursor is instantly. I don't know how to change that, because I am only starting with HTML, and the way I learn is very hard - messing around with stuff. I need a good explanation to understand how it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moving an object towards a point in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762079/moving-an-object-towards-a-point-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just directly copying the destination coordinate to the object you're moving:

```
  Slendyman.x = Forest.x;
  Slendyman.y = Forest.y;
```

This is what instantly transports `Slendyman` to `Forest`. What you need to do instead is:

1. Point `Slendyman`'s motion vector towards `Forest`.
2. Move `Slendyman` along that vector a certain amount.

Basically,  what you need is to do some trigonometry (NEVER ignore math in highschool!!).

OK. So first we need to find the direction we want to move:

```
                           o  Forest
                          /.
                         / .
                        /  .   DY
                       /   .
                      /    .
          Slendyman  o . . .

                        DX
```

First we figure out the X and Y distances between Slendyman and Forest:

```
var DX = Forest.x - Slendyman.x;
var DY = Forest.y - Slendyman.y;
```

From that we can get the angle between Slendyman and Forest. You notice that if the angle we want is between the X axis and the line joining Slendyman and Forest then the *tan* of the angle is DY/DX. Therefore the angle is `arctan(DY/DX)`.

However, there is a problem with this. Remember that the value of *tan* can sometimes be infinity. This will crash our program. The safest bet is to use either `arcsin` or `arccos`. For that we first need to know the length of the hypotenuse (the line connecting `Slendyman` and `Forest`). We can use Pythagoras:

```
var HYP = Math.sqrt(DX*DX + DY*DY);
```

OK. Now we have all we need to find the direction `Slendyman` should move in. Let's use `sine`. We know that `sine` is `opposite / hypotenuse`, so the angle we want is `arcsine(opposite / hypotenuse)`:

```
var direction = Math.asin(DY / HYP);
```

Now that we have direction we can move. Say for example you want to move 10 pixels:

```
var move_distance = 10;
var y_motion = move_distance * Math.sin(direction);
var x_motion = move_distance * Math.cos(direction);

Slendyman.x += x_motion;
Slendyman.y += y_motion;
```

You can change the speed by changing the move_distance.

Comment: I've already shown you: the problematic part is just two lines in your code I highlighted. Replace those two lines with the 9 lines of code above. Your objctive is to get `Slendyman.x = something` and `Slendyman.y = something` working and I've shown you how.

Comment: For some reason it won't move to the left, but it can move in all other directions.