# Adding "speed" to a "MoveTowards(start, target)" function

Tags: javascript, math

I implemented the following function:

```
function moveTowards(start, target, speed) {
    if (Math.abs(target.x - start.x) < config.COLLISION_RADIUS
        && Math.abs(target.y - start.y) < config.COLLISION_RADIUS) { 
        return target 
    }
    const newX = target.x - start.x
    const newY = target.y - start.y
    const angle = Math.atan2(newY, newX)
    const x = speed * Math.cos(angle)
    const y = speed * Math.sin(angle)

    return {
        x: start.x + x,
        y: start.y + y
    }
}
```

It is expected to be called in a games update loop and returns a position that slowly moves towards the target position.

It works fine however when I set a speed greater than 1 the function never actually meets the target position but returns positions in the area around the target.

I took the math from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20762210/5547718

The solutions there dont contain a speed parameter, rather a "magnitude".

How could I implement a variable speed without never arriving at the target?

(I tried just accepting values that are "close enough" but the greater the speed the higher differences I must tolerate which doesnt work out practicly)

Comment: The code seems to lack of checking, if the distance required is less then the calculated distance would be traveled

Comment: @BalazsVago I edited my question to include that code. The result is the same. COLLISION_RADIUS is 2

Comment: I would rather calculate the distance between the start, and target, then calculate the distance to be traveled, if the new travel distance is greater then the initial distance, then hit

Comment: Wow, life saver. That worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Your code does a lot of unnecessary calculations every frame. For example, you should only have these calculations:

```
const angle = Math.atan2(newY, newX);
const x = speed * Math.cos(angle);
const y = speed * Math.sin(angle);
```

Done once at the beginning of the movement as opposed to every single frame (the angle deosn't change between frames).

What you could have every frame, however, is a check to see whether the distance from start to target is less than the projected distance with speed, in which case simply place the object at the target position.

```
if (newX <= x && newY <= y) {
    return target;
}
```

Comment: You're right, I could definetly optimize that. And yep, this solution works.

Comment: I would add, seeing the solution you have proposed, that you could remove the Math.sqrt functions in the comparison of distances. sqrt is an expensive function (for every single frame) and for the purposes of comparison, the squared distances are just as useful as the sqrt distances.

Comment: When using just (newX < x && newY < y) I encounter a bug where the player teleports directly to the target when the target is in the upper left direction of the player. So wait, you just mentioned I should use the squared distances. That would be (newX * newX < x*x ...) right?

Comment: What if the target is also moving?  Then the angle could change between frames.

Comment: (newX * newX <= x * x && newY * newY <= y * y) works perfectly as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Balazs's and @Michael's advice I did the following and it worked out perfectly:

```
function moveTowards(start, target, speed) {
    const newX = target.x - start.x
    const newY = target.y - start.y
    const angle = Math.atan2(newY, newX)
    const x = speed * Math.cos(angle)
    const y = speed * Math.sin(angle)

    if (newX*newX <= x*x && newY*newY <= y*y)
        return target

    return {
        x: start.x + x,
        y: start.y + y
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't need to square those values either! if newX*newX is inferior to x*x then newX is inferior to x. So simply using `newX <= x && newY <= y` is enough. As for my comments in my answer regarding calculations every frame, if the target is moving then indeed these calculations are necessary every frame.

Comment: Please have a look at this: https://imgur.com/a/pvV9Qst When I do not square the values and move the mouse(target) to the upper left of the circle (start), it jumps to the mouse instantly. When I square the values however this does NOT occure. Do you know why?

Comment: I am guessing its due to negativ values lol. Using Math.abs resolves this problem. What would be more efficient though?

Comment: oops! My fault. I'm not taking into account negative values. You want to use `Math.abs(newX) <= Math.abs(x)`. Squaring the values will always return a positive number, which is why it works. To be honest, multiplication is much less expensive that sqrt so it's not a huge deal, but that's the reason why the weirdness is happening.

Comment: Question is, is multiplication faster than Math.abs() as well?